# How to fix this undefined control error in my document?

Tags: chapters, article

```
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Complex Numbers}
Complex numbers play important role in mathematics and in sciences. The use of complex numbers is indispensable in Physics.
Real Numbers: All numbers whose square is positive $(x^2?0)$ are known as real     numbers.
Imaginary Numbers: Besides real numbers there are numbers whose square gives negative $(x^2<0)$ are called imaginary numbers.
For example, consider the following equations:
$x^2+1=0$,$x^2+4=0$,$x^2+5=0$,…
The equation  $x^2+1=0$
Or has no solution among the real numbers. Thus we can not find a real number that can satisfy the above equation. Similarly, $x^2+4=0$,$x^2+5=0$ and so on.
To resolve this issue, Mathematicians introduced a new number denoted by a Greek letter of alphabet i(iota) such that $i=?(-1)$ which is called the imaginary unit. If we square both sides of Eq. (1), we have $i^2=-1$ a result that can not be obtained with real numbers. Using this new new number iota we can also define the imaginary numbers as: `` All numbers having iota in their factorization are called imaginary numbers.'' A simple consequences of the definition of iota is that all powers of iota may be expressed in terms of ±1 or i itself.

%\begin{figure}[h]
%\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1]{Noor1.eps}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have several non-ASCII characters in such as `…` and `±`.

Comment: `article` has no chapters. Use `book` if you want them. By the way, why loading `amssymb` ***five*** times and `amsmath` ***four*** times?

Comment: @egreg Brother I don't know, please set this if possible, i can only write in latex don't know how to set up.

Comment: In addition to that `fixltx2e` should not be needed any more.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't agree in any respect to your description of complex numbers. It's really very disputable from a mathematician's point of view and very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get is:

`! Undefined control sequence.
l.35 \chapter`

You get this error message, because you can't use `chapter` in combination with the `article` documentclass.

You have the following 2 possibilities:

1. use the `report`  documentclass instead.
2. stay with the `article` documentclass and replace `\chapter` with `\section`.

Comment: Brother I know thanks is not good, we should just up vote or down vote but you are so good to latex, thank you so much